# Set Default Google cloud print preview instead the default windows print UI

Tags: c#, printing, google-cloud-print, eo.webbrowser

I am using a web browser build in c #. When the page calls Windows.Print it calls the Windows default print preview. I would like to set Google cloud print as default. I am using EO. Web browser as a web browser.
Is there any way to do it?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you aware that google cloud print is no longer supported as of. 31 December 2020.